# CreateCriteria inside Expression.Disjunction() fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, createcriteria

```
criteriaCount.CreateCriteria(AdvertisementsProperties.City.ToString())
                .Add(Expression.Like(CitiesProperties.Name.ToString(), query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                .Add(Expression.Like(CitiesProperties.SlovenianName.ToString(), query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                .CreateCriteria(AdvertisementsProperties.Country.ToString())
                .Add(Expression.Like(CountriesProperties.Name.ToString(), query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                .Add(Expression.Like(CountriesProperties.SlovenianName.ToString(), query, MatchMode.Anywhere));
```

---

This return "name like %foo% and slovenianName like %foo% and name like %foo% and slovenianName like %foo%"

but i would like to get "name like %foo% or slovenianName like %foo% or name like %foo% or slovenianName like %foo%"

i can use Expression.Disjunction() for OR but i have problem that i can not use CreateCriteria inside Expression.Disjunction(). Can someone tell me how can i use OR and CreateCriteria together?

Regards

Comment: You need to give us more information. Show us your entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CreateAlias outside the Disjunction().

```
var result = session.CreateCriteria<Property>()
    .CreateAlias("Cities", "city")
    .CreateAlias("Countries", "country")
    .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Expression.Like("city.Name", query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
        .Add(Expression.Like("city.SlovenianNam", query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
        .Add(Expression.Like("country.Name", query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
        .Add(Expression.Like("country.SlovenianNam", query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
    ).List();
```

The corresponding entites are below. Hopefully they resemble yours.

```
class Property
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<City> Cities { set; get; }
    public virtual IList<Country> Countries { set; get; }
}

class City
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string SlovenianNam{ get; set; }
}

class Country
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string SlovenianNam{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above example works good because both of othere classes are the constitutions of Property class.

If it is in this  order it doesn't work.

class Property{
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     publice virtual string name { get; set;}
     Public virtual City city {get; set;} //many to one
}

class City {
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual country country { get; set; } //many to one
 }

class Country {
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}